# Why ReLU is better than the other activation functions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent, activation-function

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/sigmoid-vs-relu-function-in-convnets) the answer refers to vanishing and exploding gradients that has been in `sigmoid`-like activation functions but, I guess, `Relu` has a disadvantage and it is its expected value. there is no limitation for the output of the `Relu` and so its expected value is not zero. I remember the time before the popularity of `Relu` that `tanh` was the most popular amongst machine learning experts rather than `sigmoid`. The reason was that the expected value of the `tanh` was equal to zero and and it helped learning in deeper layers to be more rapid in a neural net. `Relu` does not have this characteristic, but why it is working so good if we put its derivative advantage aside. Moreover, I guess the derivative also may be affected. Because the activations (output of `Relu`) are involved for calculating the update rules.

Comment: It is common to have some sort of normalization (e.g. batch normalization, layer normalization) together with ReLU. This adjusts the output range.

Comment: @ncasas But in typical `CNN` normalizing the output of the `relu` is not common? At least I have never seen that.

Comment: You are right, in not very deep CNNs it is normal not to have batch normalization. Have you considered the role of weight initial values? (e.g. He initialization)

Comment: yes, actually they are for somehow preventing vanishing/exploding gradients, after some iterations the outputs get larger I guess.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The biggest advantage of ReLu is indeed non-saturation of its gradient, which greatly accelerates the convergence of stochastic gradient descent compared to the sigmoid / tanh functions ([paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf) by Krizhevsky et al).

But it's not the only advantage. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/176905/130598) is a discussion of sparsity effects of ReLu activations and induced regularization. Another nice property is that compared to tanh / sigmoid neurons that involve expensive operations (exponentials, etc.), the ReLU can be implemented by simply thresholding a matrix of activations at zero.

But I'm not convinced that great success of modern neural networks is due to ReLu *alone*. New initialization techniques, such as Xavier initialization, dropout and (later) batchnorm also played very important role. For example, famous AlexNet used ReLu *and* dropout.

So to answer your question: ReLu has very nice properties, though [not ideal](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks). But it truly proves itself when combined with other great techniques, which by the way solve non-zero-center problem that you've mentioned.

UPD: ReLu output is not zero-centered indeed and it does hurt the NN performance. But this particular issue can be tackled by other regularization techniques, e.g. batchnorm, which [normalizes the signal before activation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167):

> We add the BN transform immediately before the nonlinearity, by
>   normalizing $x = Wu+ b$. ... normalizing it is likely to produce
>   activations with a stable distribution.

Comment: I should've stressed this part: I was trying to say that ReLu alone doesn't solve this issue. You are right that ReLu output is not zero-centered and it does hurt the NN performance, *unless* the weights are regularized. But saturated gradients hurt the NN even more, so mass adoption of ReLu was a step forward despite its disadvantages.

Comment: would you please say what do you mean by weights are regularized? in the answer and also the thing that you have emphasized.

Comment: Updated my answer with some details about this particular issue

Comment: What i find a bit confusing, why not just use the identity function? Whats the advantage of 0 for neg values?

Comment: @Alex id is not a non-linearity. It's equivalent to having only linear layers in the NN. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46659525/712995

Comment: 'flexibly squash the input through a function and pave the way recovering a higher-level abstraction structure', ok but why not use squared function for pos values? It will produce a far more intetesting derivative for example

Comment: I'm not aware if anyone has tried $x^2$ activation function in research. My guess is that it will suffer from gradient saturation as well - see exploding gradients problem. Relu is the first activation that managed to solve it

Comment: "suffer from gradient saturation"..."exploding gradients problem" - these are clearly mutually exclusive. Do you mean that the linear derivative will grow unrestrictred?

Answer (score 1):

I think normalization issues are minor issues in numerical computations in general and machine learning in particular if you do not encounter significant numerical overflow or underflow.

The expected value issue is one of the normalization issues.

I know many people disagree with this claim. It is fine if you have the time to make all values close to 1 so that you get perfect numerical accuracy.

I usually use Relu and ignore all the normalization issues.