# Are non-relu activations better for small/ dense datasets?

Tags: neural-network, activation-function, theory

Building on the questions below, the only conclusion I could draw from the answers was that `ReLu` is less computationally expensive and better at sparsity.

> [Why is ReLU used as an activation function?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26475/why-is-relu-used-as-an-activation-function)
>
> [Why ReLU is better than the other activation functions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23493/why-relu-is-better-than-the-other-activation-functions)

Am I better off using a smoother activation like `tanh` if I have a smaller, dense dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to to predict tanh would be better if for a smaller, dense dataset.

The effect of activation function varies from dataset to dataset. You could it treat like an empirical question - find the best activation function for a specific data set like any other hyperparameter.