# Why do we use the RELU activation function?

Tags: neural-network, mathematics, activation-function

I reading about activation functions in feedforward neural networks.
ad a really old paper [https://web.njit.edu/~usman/courses/cs677_spring21/hornik-nn-1991.pdf](https://web.njit.edu/%7Eusman/courses/cs677_spring21/hornik-nn-1991.pdf).

They prove that by using arbitrary bounded and non-constant functions then, we can approximate anything function we want which is the heart of machine learning.
So I wonder why RELU is used because it would directly violate the theorem as RELU is unbounded.

I understand the reasoning that people use for using RELU that it combats exploding gradients of other activations and seems to work well etc.
I am mainly confused about the activation functions that are not bounded as it violates the theorem, maybe I haven't delved deep enough into the literature to learn this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why ReLU is better than the other activation functions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23493/why-relu-is-better-than-the-other-activation-functions)

Comment: @timmy1691, the theorem does not say that unbounded activations cannot model arbitrary functions. It just focuses on some conditions and derives some conclusions. However, proving A → B is not equivalent to proving !A → !B.

Comment: @noe yes i realized that a few hours after posting the question, i wonder if there is a proof that proves the ¬A to ¬B?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03654.pdf) offers a proof of unbounded → universal approximation. I also find [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525710/40048) relevant.